Nested quotes in f-string with Python 3.12 vs older versions
With Python 3.12 I can do the following without error:
a = "abc"
s = f"{a.replace("b", "x")}"

Note the nested " characters.
With Python 3.6 the same will throw a SyntaxError because closing ) and } are missing in this part f"{a.replace(".
Why is that? I would have expected a SyntaxError with 3.12 as well.

You're running two different Python versions.

It IS a syntax error.  You must be using different double quotes, like Word's fancy double quotes.

I expect a syntax error. But it doesn't happen on Windows. Granted, it's Python 3.12 on Windows, 3.6 on Linux, but syntax errors should be consistent across platforms, imho.

FWIW, in this particular case, the f-string is completely superfluous to begin with.

Edited the question to clarify, why it's not a duplicate of the linked question.

Python 3.12 implements PEP 701, that allows the usage of the same quote character as the outer f-string itself
>>> songs = ['Take me back to Eden', 'Alkaline', 'Ascensionism']
>>> f"This is the playlist: {", ".join(songs)}"
'This is the playlist: Take me back to Eden, Alkaline, Ascensionism'

So if you are running 3.12 on one system and an older version on the other, the difference is to be expected.

You can change the " to '
s = f'{a.replace("b", "x")}'

